# Is port-scanning my own WiFi network illegal in Australia?

Tags: internet, australia, is-x-legal

I've recently been drawn into pen-testing and port-scanning and I wanted to give it a try. I am unsure of the laws around port-scanning in Australia. Could I get in trouble with my WiFi provider if I scanned my network?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely legal question, try [law.se] instead. Apart from that: if you have a WiFi provider (instead of setting up your own WiFi) then it is most likely not your own network but a network you are allowed to use (but not own) and any activity there might negatively affect other users of the network. It is therefore likely that the WiFi provider does not allow such activity - check your terms of service.

Comment: Do you own all of the network equipment, or is it provided by your ISP?

Comment: Please define "WiFi provider".